# NSMutableArray question

Tags: nsmutablearray

Can you reset a nsmutable array it after deletions to put it back to its original state with all the initial variables before deletions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to delete everything, and then magically bring it all back? You can't.

If you want to be able to undo stuff, you need to write code that remembers deleted information in anticipation of the possibility of needing to undo.

Comment: You see what I want to do is have a double picker with card and suit. There is 7 cards to be picked and a card can only be chosen once so to stop repetition a selected card has to be deleted from the array. The issue is there is a reset button which will reset all cards so in essence there would be no selections so the picker would have all the cards as it did at the beginning of the application is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is. Just copy the original sequence and store it somewhere.

Comment: nice 1 I was thinking that but wanted to see if there was a different way

Answer (score 0):

No, but if memory isn't an issue, you could duplicate the array before the deletion.